# GitPython push JSON truncation

Tags: gitpython

I'm using the following in Windows to push a file to git (using GitPython) that has been dumped by the JSON library:

```
json.dump(data, json_output,sort_keys=True)

repo.git.add("test.json")
repo.git.commit(m="test")
repo.remotes.origin.push(repo.head)
```

The file arrives OK but when I view it in BitBucket it has been truncated:

(partial output of end of line)
"logger_severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_INFO"}, {"logger_obje  <--truncated

However, if I use git bash and simply use git push origin master it looks fine in BitBucket:

(partial output shown)
, "name": "Liberate Anguilla - dev02"}

Any ideas?

Comment: Also tried adding indent=4 to json.dump so that it looks 'readable' but the same truncation occurs (although at a different place). Perhaps there is a limit in GitPython as to the size of a file it can push (this one truncates at line 725)?